# Why is the parasitic inductance placed in series with the resistance in the treatment of a real resistance?

Tags: components, inductance

As seen in the following image, the parasitic inductance is placed in series with the real resistance.

[image: Real resistance]

I do not understand that it is the reason for this decision, whether by convention or there is a reasoning behind it. It's probably a trivial question, but I'm starting to study electronics and I'd like to understand this basic thing.

Comment: Because the physics works that way.

Comment: This is the lead inductance of the resister. This will be in series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inductance must be in series because if it were in parallel with the resistor then the dc resistance would always be \$0 \Omega\$.

The capacitor must be in parallel because if it were in series the dc resistance would always be \$\infty \Omega\$.

These elements are where they are because the inductance tends to increase the impedance at high frequency while the capacitance tends to decrease the impedance at high frequency.